On how to produce videos like this one
I wonder how can one produce (basic perhaps) videos like this one
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_0x6mUQ204
Is that some kind of tablet or device that offers users the ability to do so, or is it some kind of software that is meant to be installed on windows pc.
Thanks for any advice.

This question would be substantially improved if the title and body of the question described the video you are attempting to produce rather than requiring users to watch something off-site.

I have closed this as a duplicate because I think that the earlier question basically addresses this question---it is a combination of hardware and software, and the answers to the linked question cover potential solutions.

I use goodnotes on a ipad and get similar results. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uer0HfXUvJU
The Goodnotes app is very inexpensive. It probably works well on other tablets too. I am not using an external microphone. The audio with my tablet's microphone sounds fine to me.
It takes some practice to get good at this, but I'd say practice is the main thing.


There are a lot of different tablet programs.  Some free, even.  Plus, really you can even just do acetate and grease pencil.

The key technology thing to start making decent video content is a separate microphone.  You don't even need the most expensive one.  But get a real separate one, not relying on your computer.


